# Generate new field csv python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

I have this csv file:

```
movieId;title;genres
1;Toy Story (1995);Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2;Jumanji (1995);Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3;Grumpier Old Men (1995);Comedy|Romance
4;Waiting to Exhale (1995);Comedy|Drama|Romance
5;Father of the Bride Part II (1995);Comedy
6;Heat (1995);Action|Crime|Thriller
7;Sabrina (1995);Comedy|Romance
8;Tom and Huck (1995);Adventure|Children
9;Hate (Haine, La) (1995);Crime|Drama
10;Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995);Mystery|Thriller
```

I'd like to generate a new field called year from the field title, since the field title contains also the year of the movie.
I tried in this way but it doesn't work:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/IMDB.csv")
str=df
str1="(19"
str2="(20"
str3="(21"
str.find(str1, beg=0, end=len(string))
str.find(str1, beg=0, end=len(string)) 
str.find(str1, beg=0, end=len(string))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by regex for values between parentheses if contains numeric with length 4:

```
df['year'] = df['title'].str.extract('\((\d{4})\)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (df)
   movieId                               title  \
0        1                    Toy Story (1995)   
1        2                      Jumanji (1995)   
2        3             Grumpier Old Men (1995)   
3        4            Waiting to Exhale (1995)   
4        5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)   
5        6                         Heat (1995)   
6        7                      Sabrina (1995)   
7        8                 Tom and Huck (1995)   
8        9             Hate (Haine, La) (1995)   
9       10         Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995)   

                                        genres  year  
0  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995  
1                   Adventure|Children|Fantasy  1995  
2                               Comedy|Romance  1995  
3                         Comedy|Drama|Romance  1995  
4                                       Comedy  1995  
5                        Action|Crime|Thriller  1995  
6                               Comedy|Romance  1995  
7                           Adventure|Children  1995  
8                                  Crime|Drama  1995  
9                             Mystery|Thriller  1995
```

Comment: I wrote this: 
`import pandas`
`df=pandas.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/IMDB.csv")`
`df['year'] = df['title'].str.extract('\((\d{4})\)', expand=False).astype(int)`
`print (df)`

Comment: @P.ru - Yes? And some problem?

Comment: It worked until a minutes ago, now if I launch the .py I get this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    df['year'] = df['title'].str.extract('\((\d{4})\)', expand=False).astype(int)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column...
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'title'`

Comment: @P.ru - It means there is no column `title`, what return `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: It returns the same error. But the code that I posted worked until few minutes ago, I don't know why it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: hmm, hard to know, sometimes help restart IDE.

Comment: I also restarted the computer but it doesn't work, incredible :/

Comment: If use only `df=pandas.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/IMDB.csv")` print (df) it working?

Comment: There is some problem with pandas :( because cannot print dataframe. I mka afraid but semes need reinstall pandas.

Comment: I also tried to reinstall both python and pandas, but it still has the same problem. :(

Comment: @P.ru - So if use `import pandas df=pandas.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/IMDB.csv")` and then `print (df)` it still failed?

Comment: If I try in this way the error is:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax in the 1st line

Comment: hmm, maybe problem with `"` because copy ? How working with `r"/Users/Desktop/IMDB.csv"` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169192/discussion-between-p-ru-and-jezrael).

Comment: I get it. Need `df=pandas.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/IMDB.csv", sep=';')`